# Rebase, but ignoring one upstream commit?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I'm trying out git for local workflow management, with an eye toward proposing it for my team. So I'd like to fully get my head around it, and I'm coming up against something I don't understand.

Where I came into git-land was, I had a SVN repository that has me and one other developer working on it. Our PM changed the project timeline such that his sub-project needs to go to production almost immediately, followed by mine in about a month. We're both developing in the same SVN repo, and my stuff is already starting to be visible to the user, and so needs to be backed out for the upcoming production migration.

I updated my SVN working directory. I initied a git repository in that same directory (ignoring .svn, etc). I did `git branch map-dev` to create a development branch for my (map-related) sub-project. I did `git checkout master` to get back to the SVN-synced branch, and edited those files to take out my work. Once the early parts of my project were no longer visible, I committed to git (with the comment "map search stuff rendered invisible"), committed to SVN, and pushed the SVN content to staging. So now what's up on the staging/test server has none of my stuff and all of his, and that's fine.

A few days later, I've developed along in my `map-dev` branch, and my colleague has checked in some stuff to SVN that doesn't REALLY impact what I'm doing, but I'd like to stay in sync with.

I `git checkout master`. I `svn up`. I `git commit -a` with the comment "update from SVN".

Now I think, okay, rebase `map-dev` with those changes in master, right? So I do that, I resolve a conflict or two, and everything seems hunky-dory. Then I notice that the changes I committed on `master` called "map search stuff rendered invisible" are what's current. There ISN'T a more recent commit on my dev branch, it was just how that stuff was when the repo was first committed.

So. I used `git revert --hard ORIG_HEAD` to get back to where I was before the rebase. What I want is the CSV changes I just put in `master` but NOT the commit that made my work invisible. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest merging his code into your dev branch:

```
git checkout map_dev
git merge master
```

Then revert your commit that removed your code:

```
git revert <sha1>
```

Where  is the SHA1 of the commit that removed your code from `master`. Now you'll have his code in your `map_dev` branch, minus your cleanup. It'll make merging your code back into `master` easier, when you get there.

Edit: Alternatively, it may be easier (resulting in a cleaner merge) if you do something more like this:

```
git checkout master -b temp
git revert <sha1 of code removal>
git checkout map_dev
git merge temp
git branch -d temp
```

This will put the revert of the code removal at the top of your branch, which may cause fewer merge conflicts. I can't say for certain.

Comment: Thanks! Will I need to do that every time I bring in SVN updates? Because this is going to keep happening.

Comment: After that one, you should be able to just merge `master` into `map_dev` without going through all the extra steps. Those steps were there to remove your code removal commit from `master`, which shouldn't need to be done again.

Comment: ...because the revert of it will be at the tip of map_dev in a merge commit. Got it.

Comment: That did it, thanks. Now should I be using rebase to pull in updates from the master branch from now on?

Comment: Once you've merged once (and you have), you're better off sticking with merging. In the future, if you start a new feature on a new branch (without needing to revert anything), rebasing is a good approach to keep yourself at the tip of master without creating ugly history.